# how to get pointer of pointer of a object in `C`

Tags: c, pointers

I have a struct variable

```
      struct Var var;
```

and a function which is from a library

```
      void func(struct Var ** ){}
```

now I want to call this function
can I use

```
      func(&&var);
```

if so, is there anything to be cautious?
if not, any solutions?

thanks!

Comment: There's no need to be cautious in this particular case, because the function does nothing :)

Comment: Could you tell us the reason to pass your static var as double pointer. Because there is no sense for that

Comment: Yes, you have to. Ask WHY that function accepts a pointer to pointer...does it work with a temporary pointer to an allocated struct? Does it make sense?

Comment: passing parameter as double pointer is usally used to get a new address for passed pointer. and in your case you are passing the address of static variable so its address will not changed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A function with an argument of type `T**` is probably going to be reassigning the pointer to a different value. This means that the address of a `T*` must be passed in:

```
struct Var* var;
func(&var);

void func(struct Var ** a_var)
{
    *a_var = malloc(sizeof(struct Var));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this by following declaration :

```
struct Var *var;
func(&var);
```

Situation : In these ex, you declare pointer variable in one function and `allocate` memory in `func()`

Answer (score 2):

The `&` operator takes an address of an expression, which must be an lvalue (i.e. something that can appear on the left side of an assignment). The `&var` expression *cannot* appear on the left side of an assignment, so taking an address of `&var` in `& (&var)` is not allowed.

In order to pass an address of an address you need to create a pointer variable first, assign an address of a thing to that pointer, and then pass an address of a pointer, like this:

```
struct Var myVar; // Initialize myVar
struct Var *ptr = &myVar; // First level of indirection - pointer to struct
func(&ptr); // Second level of indirection - pointer to a pointer
```

Answer (score 0):

passing parameter as double pointer is usally used to get a new address for passed pointer. and in your case you are passing the address of static variable so its address will not changed

Comment: @user1944267 I could not confirm if is correct or not or in which cases is correct but I do not see any sense to use it